# Regex help, find between : text

Tags: php, regex

how i can select with regex this: http://prntscr.com/6dfdzf 
Example I have:

```
my dad sees : aqwe kayak at noon : night
```

and it should give my only:

```
sees : aqwe, noon:night
```

Comment: Give us a more concrete example of what you're trying to filter/keep. Do you want to remove "my dad" and "kayak at" or what is the actual pattern you're going for? You want a comma separated list of every word surrounding the colon?

Comment: i don't why you mentioned a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\S+\s*:\s*\S+
```

This simple regex should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/24